# ionic app: file url: system open with dialog

Tags: file, ionic-framework

Is it possible to show a native "Open With" dialog suggesting recommended apps, when the user taps on a http link (to a file download) in an ionic application?

Thanks,
Anil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Simply you can use **[Cordova InAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/inappbrowser/inappbrowser.html)** to implement it.
Try below code after adding plugin:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(file_link, '_system', 'location=yes');
```

To be more specific you can use some other plugins such as **[cordova-plugin-fileopener](https://github.com/Smile-SA/cordova-plugin-fileopener)**.

Comment: Thanks, l try both out n reply back

Comment: cordova.InAppBrowser.open(file_link, '_system', "location=yes"); --> its a working mechanism but probably not the one I am looking for as this switches to browser to download the file. Cordova file opener looks promizing. trying that out.

Comment: yep.. file opener worked.. Now I need to figure out a way to get all possible mime types.

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than an installed app which support this type, the os open automatically a open with dialog