# how can i download videos from firebase storage?

Tags: ionic-framework

How can I download videos from Firebase storage by clicking on a Buttun in ionic?
i didn't see anything in ionic docs except for notifications. I tried another solutions like dropbox but I didn't see API for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the file link with:

```
 afStorage.ref(refInStorage).getDownloadURL().subscribe(fileLink => )
```

Then the easy way it's open the file link in the default browser:

```
 window.open(fileLink, '_system');
```

Other workaround is open inside and with the help of [InAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html) or FileOpener([StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584051/ionic-app-file-url-system-open-with-dialog))

All together:

```
 afStorage.ref(refInStorage).getDownloadURL()
         .subscribe(fileLink => window.open(fileLink, '_system'))
```